# Notarisation on macOS Sonoma

Tags: macos, code-signing, notarization

Is notarisation required to execute code on macOS Sonoma.

Note, I'm not speaking about code sign, where the binary is signed with any key (which is acceptable prior to Sonoma) but rather notarisation, where Apple countersign your code.

For locally built/executed CLI tools, is notarisation required?

Comment: Related:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution